# ismember for string-matrix cell elements in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

ismember checks for cell-array or matrix elements.  How do we check for string-numeric elements together?  Please see below:

```
cell1 = {'netincome' [1] ; 'equity' [2] }  ;

cell2 = { 'cogs' [2222] [1] ; 'equity' [3501] [2] ; 

          'equity' [3333] [1] ; 'netincome' [1751] [1] } ;
```

This fails ->ismember(cell1(:,[1 2]), cell2(:,[1 3])  % I know why it fails.

Is there any way to match string elements and numeric elements from 2 cells?  I tried using ismember independently (cell2mat func was used) but still can't hit the right answer.  The desired answer is:

```
[1751 ; 3501] ; OR 'netincome' [1751] [1] ; 'equity' [3501] [2]
```

Comment: A couple questions: Are the entries in `cell1` and `cell2` unique (i.e. no repeats)? Are the entries in `cell1` guaranteed to have a match in `cell2`?

Comment: Ans1. `cell1` entries are unique when you consider col1 & col2 together.  `cell2` entries are NOT unique for col1 and col3. Certain rows can be repeated  Ans2. Yes, always!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any good built-in solution for this situation. The best one I can think up at the moment is to create two nested loops to compare all the rows of each cell array, using the function [ISEQUAL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isequal.html) to do the comparisons:

```
index = zeros(size(cell1,1),1);
for row1 = 1:size(cell1,1)
  for row2 = 1:size(cell2,1)
    if isequal(cell1(row1,:),cell2(row2,[1 3]))
      index(row1) = row2;
      break
    end
  end
end
```

The result will be a set of match indices in the N-by-1 vector `index`, where N is the number of rows in `cell1`. If a row of `cell1` can't be matched to the data in any row of `cell2`, then the corresponding entry of `index` will be 0. Indices of matches in `index` will preserve the original order of the data in `cell1`. Also, this code ignores multiple matches in `cell2`, returning only the index of the first match found and breaking the inner loop (which will potentially reduce the number of iterations needed).

Now you can index into `cell2` to get the data corresponding to what's in `cell1`:

```
>> cell2(index,:)

ans = 

    'netincome'    [1751]    [1]
    'equity'       [3501]    [2]
```

Comment: Thanks gnovice.  Its important that I maintain the order!  Can you suggest the changes?  Would appreciate.

Comment: @Maddy: I've updated my answer so that the order is maintained.

Comment: Hi.. please see my response to your 1Q.  I am trying to see if repetitions in cell2 can be taken care of/removed.  Let me know if you have any comments.  Thanks.

Comment: One approach is to run cell2 using http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25917-unique-rows-for-a-cell-array and then input it's result to your code.

Comment: @Maddy: If there are repeated rows in `cell2`, like `{'equity' 3501 2}` appearing multiple times, and you only need to match 1 of them, then the above code will work fine as is. If you have rows like `{'equity' 3501 2}` and `{'equity' 3333 2}`, where everything but the second column is repeated, you have some decisions to make. If you still only need to match one, and you either don't care which one or you want to use the first one, then the above code will still work fine as is. If you need to match *all* occurrences or match based on a condition, the code will need a few small modifications.